# Is there a "Link Hints" (à-la Vimium) plugin for Vim, to quickly select windows/buffers/tabs?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am looking for a plugin that would be able to display link hints over (in descending order of preference) :

- windows
- tabs
- buffers

### Example

To try and define what a link hint is (taking the example of link hints to switch between windows): a short sequence of character, that is displayed on-demand over each instance of a window in the editor. The sequence is distinct for each window. After displaying the hints, the user can enter the sequence associated to one window, to move the focus to it.

Does such plugin exist ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of such a plugin, and it's unlikely that such exists, because there's no "on demand over this window" hook in Vim. That smells of mouse hovering, and only GVIM has a corresponding feature (cp. `:help balloon`). What some users implement is including the window / buffer number in the *statusline*, e.g.:

```
:set statusline+=\ %{winnr()}
```

With that, you can then use the number with `[N]<C-w><C-w>` to quickly move to that window. For numbering tabs (if you have that many that it matters), you could use `'tabline'` / `'guitablabel'` and `tabpagenr()`.

You can easily add these customizations in your `~/.vimrc`, but because of the tight coupling with other personal preferences, this is hard to provide by a separate plugin.